# How to cast generic type T to interface?

Tags: c#, generics

I wrote a generic update method like following:

```
int UpdateBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filterExpression, Expression<Func<T, T>> updateExpression) where T : class, new()
{
    int result;
    //if T implements IModel interface, then I would like to modify pdateExpression here 
    {
        //UpdateTime is the member of interface IModel, without casting T to IModel interface, this line of code will not compile
        Expression<Func<T, T>> upexp = s => new T {UpdateTime = DateTime.Now}; 
        result = GetRepository<T>().UpdateBy(filterExpression, ExpressionCombiner.Combine(updateExpression, upexp));
    }
    else
    {
        //T doesn't implement IModel interface, so update it directly
        result= GetRepository<T>().UpdateBy(filterExpression, updateExpression);
    }

    return result;
}
```

How can I make above code to compile and run correctly? thanks in advance!

Comment: Will `where T: IInterface` not work?

Comment: @john Note the `else` branch

Comment: @PatrickHofman The answer is not what I wanted. I'm not asking how to check if T implemented IModel interface, but how to cast T to IModel interface in code `Expression<Func<T, T>> upexp = s => new T {UpdateTime = DateTime.Now}; `. Thanks!

Comment: Surely you can do `IModel newT = (IModel)new T(); newT.UpdateTime = DateTime.Now;` ?

Comment: @john Thank you, but how can I pass it to upexp? If I write `IModel m = (IModel) new T();
m.UpdateTime = DateTime.Now;
Expression<Func<T,T>> upexp = s =>(T)m;`, the code will throw exception at runtime becuase upexp = s =>(T)m is not a MemberInitExpression that I need to combine.